# When I select particular date and time it should give that complete date data from table in php

Tags: php

ex:

```
$var = "2017-03-30 11:15:15";
$sql = Select *from table where date = $var;
```

Table:

```
(id) datetime

(1)  2017-03-30 4:15:15

(2)  2017-03-30 8:15:15

(3)  2017-03-30 14:15:15
```

Now I want all three records, how to do it ?

Please help me.

Comment: what is the current result of the sql ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TRY THE FOLLOWING

```
Select * from table where DATE(date) = DATE($var);
```

Comment: `DATE(date)` makes it impossible to use index on `date` column.

Comment: @peterm I don't know much about mysql, so I don't understand why selecting makes it impossible.